# R dataframe with varied column lengths

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 10 rows

```
df <- c(1:10)
```

How do I add another column to the dataframe which has only 5 rows?

```
df2 <- c(1:5)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) c() sticks things into a vector, which is a different object than a data.frame.

Comment: 2) for data.frames, see ?data.frame

Comment: 3) data.frames must of columns of equal length. for elements of unequal length, use a list(). see ?list

Comment: @timriffe That all adds up to a pretty good _answer_, IMHO. (hint hint hint!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll give some little pointers here. See Tyler's answer a few questions back for a couple links to materials for getting started:
[convert data.frame column format from character to factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251326/convert-data-frame-column-format-from-character-to-factor)

1) The objects you're making with `c()` are called vectors, and that is a particular kind of object in R- the most basic and useful kind.

2) A `data.frame` is a kind of `list` where all the elements of the list are stuck together as columns and must be of the same length. The columns can be different data types (`class`es)

3) `list`s are the most versatile kind of object in R- the elements of a list can be anything- any size, any class. This appears to be what you're asking for.

So for instance:

```
    mylist <- list(vec1 = c(1:10), vec2 = c(1:5))
    mylist
    $vec1
     [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
    $vec2
     [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

There are different ways to get back at the elements of `mylist`, e.g.

```
    mylist$vec1
    mylist[1]
    mylist[[1]]
    mylist["vec1"]
    mylist[["vec1"]]
```

and likely more! Find a tutorial by searching for 'R beginner tutorial' and power through it. Have fun!

Answer (score 11):

There are two approaches I know of to get what you're asking for BUT this may not be the best approach to the problem as others have pointed out.  What I'm going to show you I myself would not use (I'd opt for the list option most likely as Tim shows).

```
df <- data.frame(var=1:10)  #notice I created a data.frame vs. the vector you called
new.col <- c(1:5)

#METHOD 1
df$new.col <- c(new.col, rep(NA, nrow(df)-length(new.col)))  #keep as integer
#METHOD 2
df$new.col2 <- c(new.col, rep("", nrow(df)-length(new.col))) #converts to character
df                                         #look at it
str(df)                                    #see what's happening to the columns
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... 2018 and it still works! Thank you so much!!