# Applying if statement to data frame elements

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

Here is what i am trying to do:
1. Read in csv file 
2. Create a column number 107 and copy values from column 67 based on the condition:' only copy values if row values in column 70 is "Yes"'

Code:

```
report <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\ha317981\\Desktop\\practice\\input.csv",  header=1)
for(i in 1:length(report[[70]])-1){ 
    if(report[[i, 70]] =="Yes"){
      report[[i,107]] <-report[[i, 67]]  
    }
    i<- i + 1
  }
```

> Error: *Error in `[[.default`(col, i, exact = exact) : 
>     attempt to select less than one element in get1index*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your code with the vectorised operation as below.

```
report[,107] <- ifelse(report[,70] == "Yes", report[,67], NA)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package paired with `ifelse`.

From the documentation:

"Mutate adds new variables and preserves existing; transmute drops existing variables."

```
require(dplyr)
report <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\ha317981\\Desktop\\practice\\input.csv",  header=1)

# mutate(tbl_df, NewColumn = Value, ...)

newReport <- mutate(report, Col107 = ifelse(Col70 == "Yes", Col67, NA))
```

This will create a new variable in your (presumably?) data frame based on the values of Column 70, where the value will either be copied from Column 67 or `NA`.

Comment: Thanks! :) . Could you also point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem is that your code is trying to create a new column line by line, rather than creating one column that's the same length as the other columns in one statement. Data frames in R need to have all of their columns be the same length (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253303/r-dataframe-with-varied-column-lengths). To fix this, you would have to add a column before the `for` loop and _then_ change it's values line by line. You could do this by putting `report$Col107 = NA` before your `for` loop.