# how can I make a data frame from a list with different row size?

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- list(structure(list(A = c(0.1807, 0.2369, 0.2432, 0.2772, 0.2833, 
    0.3194, 0.407, 0.4507, 0.5023, 0.5064, 0.5183, 0.5414, 0.5527
    ), B = c(0.1139, 0.1417, 0.1028, 0.2472, 0.025, 0.2917, 0.3917, 
    0.4417, 0.4472, 0.4639, 0.5028, 0.5194, 0.5305)), .Names = c("A", 
    "B"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        A = c(0.1807, 0.2369, 0.2432, 0.2772, 0.2833, 0.3194, 0.407, 
        0.4507, 0.5023), B = c(0.1139, 0.1417, 0.1028, 0.2472, 0.025, 
        0.2917, 0.3917, 0.4417, 0.4472)), .Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -9L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(A = c(0.1807, 0.2369, 
    0.2432, 0.2772), B = c(0.1139, 0.1417, 0.1028, 0.2472)), .Names = c("A", 
    "B"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to have the output like this

```
A         B      A       B        A     B
0.1807  0.1139  0.1807  0.1139  0.1807  0.1139
0.2369  0.1417  0.2369  0.1417  0.2369  0.1417
0.2432  0.1028  0.2432  0.1028  0.2432  0.1028
0.2772  0.2472  0.2772  0.2472  0.2772  0.2472
0.2833  0.025   0.2833  0.025       
0.3194  0.2917  0.3194  0.2917      
0.407   0.3917  0.407   0.3917      
0.4507  0.4417  0.4507  0.4417      
0.5023  0.4472  0.5023  0.4472      
0.5064  0.4639              
0.5183  0.5028              
0.5414  0.5194              
0.5527  0.5305
```

basically putting each list aside of the other one (although they are different in size)

Comment: Can you explain why you need to transform your data this way, please? Is it just for printing / inspecting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
res <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(df, fill=NA))
res
#     A      B      A      B      A      B
#1  0.1807 0.1139 0.1807 0.1139 0.1807 0.1139
#2  0.2369 0.1417 0.2369 0.1417 0.2369 0.1417
#3  0.2432 0.1028 0.2432 0.1028 0.2432 0.1028
#4  0.2772 0.2472 0.2772 0.2472 0.2772 0.2472
#5  0.2833 0.0250 0.2833 0.0250     NA     NA
#6  0.3194 0.2917 0.3194 0.2917     NA     NA
#7  0.4070 0.3917 0.4070 0.3917     NA     NA
#8  0.4507 0.4417 0.4507 0.4417     NA     NA
#9  0.5023 0.4472 0.5023 0.4472     NA     NA
#10 0.5064 0.4639     NA     NA     NA     NA
#11 0.5183 0.5028     NA     NA     NA     NA
#12 0.5414 0.5194     NA     NA     NA     NA
#13 0.5527 0.5305     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

It is better to have column names unique in the dataset

```
colnames(res) <- make.unique(colnames(res))
```

Also, the missing values are `NA`.  If we need to `""`, change `fill=NA` to `fill=""`) i.e.

```
do.call(cbind.fill, c(df, fill=''))
```

, but that will also change the `class` of the columns to `character/factor`

Answer (score 1):

The code below will produce something which *looks* very similar to your expected output:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- colnames(df[[1L]])
long <- rbindlist(df, idcol = "df.id")
wide <- dcast(long, rowid(df.id) ~ df.id, as.character, value.var = cols, fill = "")[
  , .SD, .SDcols = as.vector(outer(cols, seq_along(df), paste, sep = "_"))]
setnames(wide, rep(cols, length(df)))
wide
```

> ```
>          A      B      A      B      A      B
>  1: 0.1807 0.1139 0.1807 0.1139 0.1807 0.1139
>  2: 0.2369 0.1417 0.2369 0.1417 0.2369 0.1417
>  3: 0.2432 0.1028 0.2432 0.1028 0.2432 0.1028
>  4: 0.2772 0.2472 0.2772 0.2472 0.2772 0.2472
>  5: 0.2833  0.025 0.2833  0.025              
>  6: 0.3194 0.2917 0.3194 0.2917              
>  7:  0.407 0.3917  0.407 0.3917              
>  8: 0.4507 0.4417 0.4507 0.4417              
>  9: 0.5023 0.4472 0.5023 0.4472              
> 10: 0.5064 0.4639                            
> 11: 0.5183 0.5028                            
> 12: 0.5414 0.5194                            
> 13: 0.5527 0.5305
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible.
data.frame is a kind of list where all the elements of the list are stuck together as columns and must be of the same length. more info
[R dataframe with varied column lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253303/r-dataframe-with-varied-column-lengths)