# turn some variables in `data.frame` into `factor` keeping the data.frame structure R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to turn some of the variables in my `data.frame` into `factor` while preserving the data.frame structure. I follow the suggestions [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252447/8840683) but I don't get my desired output, any fix?

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(1,2, 3, 5), b = c(2,3, 4, 2), e = c(3,4,5,1), f = rep(c("long", "short"), 2))
factor.name <- names(d)[-4]

d[] <- lapply(seq_along(factor.name), function(i) as.factor(d[factor.name[i]]))
```

Comment: you are trying to convert columns a,b and e into factors?

Comment: for(i in factor.name ){d[,i] = factor(d[,i])}

Comment: note, the last column f is a factor by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset the data with 'factor.name', pass that in `lapply` and update the columns

```
d[factor.name] <- lapply(d[factor.name], factor)
```

Comment: Code could be cleaned up by eliminating the creation of `factor.name` with `d[,1:3] <- lapply(d[,1:3], factor)`.

Comment: @LouisPenrod  I guess the OP's `factor.name` vector would be  passed on from another function or so

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
d <-
  d %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(a, b, e), as.factor)
```